# Entity DataSource Where parameter

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entitydatasource

I have and entity **datasource** and i would like to add a where **parameter** so as to filter information. I have a gridview with a list of items and on checking a checkbox and hitting edit button, it sends you to a different view where there is a **detailsview** that has **entitydatasource** as it's DS. Now the entity **datasource** i want to add a where parameter. this is what i have so far..

```
        <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=sspEntities" DefaultContainerName="sspEntities" 
            EnableDelete="True" EnableFlattening="False" EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True"
             EntitySetName="Salary_Increase_Type" AutoGenerateWhereClause="True">
        </asp:EntityDataSource>




  Protected Sub ImageButton3_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) Handles ImageButton3.Click
        For Each dr As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
            If ((TryCast(dr.FindControl("checkbox1"), CheckBox)).Checked = True) Then
                Dim id As Integer = GridView1.DataKeys(dr.RowIndex).Value
                EntityDataSource2.WhereParameters.Clear()

                EntityDataSource2.WhereParameters.Add(id, "id")
                MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 1
                DetailsView1.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Edit)



            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: I figure it out guys. for those that want to know this:

Comment: EntityDataSource2.WhereParameters.Clear()
EntityDataSource2.WhereParameters.Add(name:="Id", dbType:=DbType.Int32, value:=id)

Comment: Feel free to post your solution as an answer, or just delete your question with the "delete" link (directly below the question).

Answer (score 0):

EntityDataSource2.WhereParameters.Clear() EntityDataSource2.WhereParameters.Add(name:="Id", dbType:=DbType.Int32, value:=id)